# RSS Feed not displaying PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, rss

I have an RSS feed which for some reason is not showing my PHP variables. When the feed is returned it comes back with the raw tags for example the title will be Timetable $yesterdayd instead of Timetable - Tuesday 10th April

```
<?PHP
 include("../config.php");
 #// Timetable Clearup Variabls
$yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');
$yesterdow = date('l',$yesterday);
$order = "SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day = '$yesterdow' ORDER BY time";
$result = mysql_query($order);
$yesterdayd = date('F jS, Y', time()-86400);

    //SET XML HEADER
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    //CONSTRUCT RSS FEED HEADERS
    $output = '<rss version="2.0">';
    $output .= '<channel>';
    $output .= '<title>Timetable - $yesterdayd </title>';
    $output .= '<description>Timetable.</description>';
    $output .= '<link>http://site.com/</link>';
 ###   $output .= '<copyright>Your copyright details</copyright>';

    //BODY OF RSS FEED
   $output .= '<item>';
        $output .= '<title>Timetable for $yesterdayd</title>';
        $output .= '<description>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</description>';
        $output .= '<link>Link to Item</link>';
        $output .= '<pubDate>Date Published</pubDate>';
   $output .= '</item> ';

    //CLOSE RSS FEED
   $output .= '</channel>';
   $output .= '</rss>';

    //SEND COMPLETE RSS FEED TO BROWSER
    echo($output);

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$output .= '<description>" . `...` . "</description>';` - here you have a quotes mismatch (`'` vs. `"`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes for the output strings. The variables don't interpolate with single quotes I think.

So like

```
$output .= "<title>Timetable for $yesterdayd</title>";
```

That should do it. The page DOES have a php extension, right?

EDIT:

When you're interpolating arrays or objects, use syntax like this {$row['username']} or {$object->property}, but when you're calling a function, you cannot interpolate, you MUST concatenate:

```
"<description>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td>";
```

Also, make sure you're not now mixing single and double quotes -- it looks like the code you pasted as a response mixes them.

Comment: this guy said everything I was going to

Answer (score 0):

single quote strings will not compute php variables.

i.e.

```
'<title>Timetable - $yesterdayd </title>';
```

should be

```
"<title>Timetable - {$yesterdayd} </title>";
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you, however one part still isn't displaying results:
`$output .= '<description>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</description>';`

Comment: `$output .= '<description>"` should be `$output .= "<description>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</description>"` otherwise php will include everything up until the next single quote.

Comment: I get this error:
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 202: Opening and ending tag mismatch: description line 0 and td
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Timetable - April 10th, 2012 Timetable.http://site.com/Timetable for April 10th, 2012

Comment: close the </td> before closing the </description> tag.

Comment: Now on the feed I am getting:
<description>
<td/>
<td/>
</description>

It's not outputting any of the data!

Comment: This:
$output .= '<description>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</description>'; SHOULD BE this: $output .= '<description>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</td></description>';

Comment: err, the quotes are wrong in that comment, but anyway you missed the closing td before description is closed. Also, if you're getting " <description> <td/> <td/> </description>" then there's something wrong with your TD tags. In fact, I'm not sure why you're using them inside of an RSS feed, I don't think you need to. Lastly, in your original post you are not opening the TD tags, so closing them isn't helping. Make sure you have "<description><td>" THEN do "</td><td>" for each item, then do "</td></description>"